# Can I implement Numpy using django?

Tags: django, numpy

Hello I need to know if django is capable to merge with Numpy, Pytables and Pandas because I'll start to work on a Business Intelligence project using Django, thus I read those tools I mentioned before are capable, but my question :

Is django capable to work with them together or I need to work just with python without framework?

Thanks, If you Have other ideas for working with OLAPS Cubes or Data analysis and Visualization using Django tell me please.

Comment: You can, though you just have to be careful when storing the objects in your database (and getting them from the database): you'd probably want to convert numpy arrays to list, for example (and masked arrays to two separate list). And in some cases you'd just write a data file, and save a pointer (filename) in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Cubes](http://cubes.databrewery.org/) : Lightweight OLAP engine in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
#html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


{{ n1 }}<br>
{{ n2 }}<br>
{{ n3 }} <br>
{{ n4 }}

</body>
</html>

#view code

# implement numpy in django


def post(request):
    n1 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
    n2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
    return render(request, 'num1.html',{'n1':n1,'n2':n2})

def multiply(request):
    n1 = np.array([[2, 3, 4],[4,5,6]])
    n2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
    n3=n1*n2
    return render(request, 'num1.html',{'n3':n3})

def zero(request):
    n4 = np.zeros((3,4))
    return render(request, 'num1.html',{'n4':n4})

#urls code`enter code here`

url(r'^post/$', views.post, name='blog'),
url(r'^multiply/$', view`enter code here`s.multiply, name='blog'),
url(r'^zero/$', views.zero, name='blog'),
```

Comment: Add explaination to your answer. Refer SO documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer